# Preselect default options in the Ui-select component of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ui-select

I'm able to load custom options into the select but I don't know how to pre-select some of these options at page load

**My UI field:**

```
<field name="products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\SourceName</item>
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
          <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
          <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
          <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
          <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">products</item>
          <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
          <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
          <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
          <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**My options source class:**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Source;

class SourceName implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
  protected $productCollection;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection
  ) {
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
  }

  public function toOptionArray()
  {

    // Load the products as options
    $products = $this->productCollection->load();
    $options = [];

    /* @todo: add query to load selected options */

    foreach ($products as $product){
      $options[] = [
        "value" => $product->getId(),
        "label" => $product->getSku()
      ];
    }

    return $options;
  }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Maybe using dataProviders? Can you provide some example to help me pre-select options ? Thanks

Comment: How you achieve dropdown with select in product edit page?

Comment: @chiragdodia it's the ui-select component of Magento, my above code shows how to achieve it. showCheckbox = true will show the checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by injecting the data into the form dataProvider:

```
$this->loadedData[$model->getId()]["products"] = ["1", "3"]; // array of ID strings
```

Comment: could you please share full code, I am also not able to populate pre selected values?

Comment: could you please share full code, I am also not able to populate pre selected values

Comment: I don't work anymore on this company project and haven't got access anymore to the code, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Use `default` argument in `config`

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

Final Code:

```
<field name="storeview">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       ...
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         ...
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
         ...
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: I need to **dinamically** preselect multiple values of this multi-select

Comment: I did not need to have this dynamically, just needed to set it in the XML, and this worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Your loop working like this 
`public function toOptionArray() 
    {
$options = [];
$options[] =

         [
            'label' => 'New Tab', 
            'value' => '_blank'
         ];

$options[] =
         [  'label' => 'Same Tab', 
            'value' => '_self'
         ];
$options[] =
         [  'label' => 'test', 
            'value' => 'test'
         ]
};`

And Please add component like below

 
`<field name="urltarget">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Targetoptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slide Url Open In</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sliders</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">urltarget</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>`

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 UI component form set default value for fields.
Add the below code xml in your field config

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

Like as:-

```
    <field name="fieldname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number"1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```